# How to call a current inventory name in the if condition in saltstate?

Tags: salt-stack

I have a simple saltstate. My question is using jinja or whatever else, how can I specify it or steps of it to run only if inventory name contains some string?

Where I can check all the saltstack variables documentation btw?

Comment: How/where is inventory name defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to target minions by grains. Salt have many grains set by default, but you can add your own grain. After adding you own "inventory" grain, you can target the minion in the top file.

Check all grains of a minion: `salt "minion" grains.items`
Set your own grain: `salt "minion" grains.set inventory inventory_num`
Target minion by new grain: `salt -G "inventory:inventory_num" test.ping`

Further information:

- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.grains.html#salt.modules.grains.set
- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/targeting/index.html
- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/grains/index.html

Comment: not interested in salt commands. Inside saltstate, like using jinja.

Comment: You can use the grains inside Jinja like this:

`{% if grains.get('inventory') == 'inventory_num' %}`